# Date picker to populate input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a default date picker that when I click the calendar button and when I choose it will reflect on the input box.

Here is my code

Html

```
<input type="date" name="date_01" class="date_01">
<input type="image" id="date_image" src="http://www.kaltimprov.go.id/view/phpmu/images/calendar_agenda.png"/>
```

CSS

```
input[type="date"].date_01{
    width:287px;
    float:left;
}

#date_image{
    width:43px;
    height:46px;
    padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px;
    border:1px solid #cbcbcb;
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

You can check that in jsfiddle also: https://jsfiddle.net/6pkjye8v/

Comment: What have you attempted? Post the code in the question (you can do it in addition to the link if you want).

Comment: hi, i don't know what to do that's why I need some help :(

Comment: Probably better to use a plugin than create your own. I recommend either Bootstrap's calendar picker: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ or datetimepicker by xdsoft: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/